# Extract string between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following problem:

```
var previous_state = response.match(simulator.previousStateString+"(.*?),");             
if( ! previous_state ) {response.match(simulator.previousStateString+"(.*?) ")};
if( ! previous_state ) {response.match(simulator.previousStateString+"(.*?)#")};
```

Basically, I am looking for a string between simulator.previousStateString and ',' or ' ' or'#'.
Is there the possibility to have a more compact code? 
I mean, can I put all 3 regex in just one?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can use this regex with [**`character class`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
response.match( new RegExp(simulator.previousStateString + "(.*?)[, #]") );
```

It matches only one out of several characters inside `[ and ]`

**PS:** Make sure there is no special regex character in `simulator.previousStateString`

Comment: To quote special regex characters see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript